# change color of bootstrap navbar dropdown menu element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar (bootstrap) with a dropdown menu.
Each item of my drowpdown menu are highlighted in blue when hovered.
What less variable is used to produce this color? I would like to change it.

Thanks

Comment: [Dropdowns variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less#L246)

Answer (score 0):

In Navbar.less, you will find your answer .
there are multiple variables,
for example.
 @navbar-default-link-color

.navbar-nav {

> li > a {
>         color: @navbar-default-link-color;

```
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: @navbar-default-link-hover-color;
    background-color: @navbar-default-link-hover-bg;
  }
}
> .active > a {
  &,
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: @navbar-default-link-active-color;
    background-color: @navbar-default-link-active-bg;
  }
}
> .disabled > a {
  &,
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    color: @navbar-default-link-disabled-color;
    background-color: @navbar-default-link-disabled-bg;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks. In variable.less, I have @navbar-default-link-hover-bg : transparent  But in my app, the color is blue. I don't understand (my knowledge in less is not very high...)

Answer (score 0):

In the file `variables.less` of the Bootstrap source code, you will find the following variables:

```
//** Global color for active items (e.g., navs or dropdowns).
@component-active-color:    #fff;
//** Global background color for active items (e.g., navs or dropdowns).
@component-active-bg:       @brand-primary;
```

Change those to configure the text and background colors (respectively)